# Sharing a JPanel with a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jdialog

I'm trying to reuse a JPanel inside a JDialog instead of replicating another JPanel that has the exact features. I tried removing and adding the component to the JDialog, but it's not working as I expected. What is the recommended approach to this issue?

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: Are you trying to have the panel at two places at once? That does not work as components can have only one parent. On the other hand, if you're adding and removing components at run time, you need to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the container.

Comment: @kiheru I'm trying to do the latter one. Is revalidate() and repaint() more efficient than copying and paste the JPanel?

Comment: Could you elaborate with code?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Revalidation is needed if you add or remove components from a visible container. I don't know what you're trying to do; it is also possible that you have situation where using a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) would be more appropriate. Please add a minimal, runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

write a class "myFeaturesJPanel" that extends jPanel having the needed features. then  just add a own instance to your popUpPanel and your original panel